# Remove defect SSD and start from new SSD in new slot

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, clone, nvme

Unfortunately my original SSD (or slot) of my HP Zbook Studio G4 is defect and results in sudden crashes (blue screens and then a 3F0 error). Therefore I would like to install a new SSD in my second slot and make my laptop run from this and remove the original SSD as it's maleficent. Can I simply create a clone of my original disk to the new SSD and remove the old and add the new to the second slot, or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Already checked the [HP support page for Error 3F0](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_3053911-2842957-16)?

Comment: Definitely follow the steps in the link dodrg shared. Is there a reason you want to plug the new drive into a different slot? Is that just for the clone process, or do you have another reason for specifying that? What have you tried? Lots of people have done this, and at least a few questions on this site come from similar scenarios: what research have you done and have you tried any of those suggestions yet?